# Installing python onto AWS Windows Workspace

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, installation

I cannot for the life of me figure out how to install python onto my AWS Windows Workspace. I keep getting Setup failed message

```
One or more issues cause the setup to fail. Please fix the issues and then retry setup. For more information see the log file. 

0x80070659 - This installation is forbidden by system policy. Contact your system administrator.
```

I tried checking the box Use admin privileges when installing py.exe. Running a custom installation and unchecking the box "for all users (requires privileges)"

Is there some setting(s) on AWS I need to change. I know that I don't have direct access to the C: directory, only D: since it's AWS. I'm thinking that could be an issue.

Could I run some command in PowerShell or something to install python directly instead of using the installer. I'm out of ideas.

I've checked the User Accounts in the Control Panel on my AWS Workspace and I am listed as Administrators

Answer (score 1):

After researching some more I was able to install Python on my AWS Workspace. It’s always annoying when you have to spend hours looking for a solution that in the end is simple and not obvious.

I changed my user account status in the control panel to be Administrators, restarted the windows instance, and right clicked the python installation driver and selected “run as administrator”.